# Url with dynamic parameters matching problem in Express (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem with a route with a dynamic GET parameter in Express 4.16 (and Node 12.1.0) : the route is never hit, but only for some values.

The route I'm trying to hit is this one :

```
app.get('/done/:taskid', function(req, res){
```

The route never matches for taskid = 0 or taskid = 1, and I just can't find out why. Works perfectly fine for taskid > 1. Actually, every value except 0 or 1 works (strings, null, whatever...).

The app doesn't crash, I'm not getting any log, but the code associated to the route is never executed and I'm just redirected to

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
```

I'm very new in NodeJS, so it might be a basic error, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Here is the complete code of my main.js :

```
const app = require('express')();
const twig = require('twig');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");
app.set('view engine', 'twig');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded());

var todolist = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.render('index.html.twig', {todolist: todolist});
});

app.get('/done/:taskid', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params);
});

app.post('/new', function(req, res){
  //insert in DB later
  todolist.push({
    name: req.body.taskName,
    done: false
  });
  res.redirect(301, '/');
});

app.listen(8000);
```

I'm trying to access it via a simple link :

```html
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="/done/0">Mark as done</a>
```

Running the app via either pm2 or node doesn't change anything.

Does someone have some insight on how I could pass an id equal to either 0 or 1 in the link and successfully match this route ?

=================

Edit : So, there was apparently no bug... or at least not related to url matching. For some reason, the request was put in "stalled" state, and for a time long enough for me to think it didn't match anything (> 1min). Which is weird, because I run this app in a docker container, on my localhost. I have only 1 tab open, and I made sure to shut down and restart the app before testing several times, so I'm pretty sure there is only 1 client making request to my app... 
I went to sleep yesterday, came back this morning, exact same code started working. 
I have seriously no idea what happened.

=================

Edit 2 : Did a bit more testing, found a pattern. Problem seems relative to chrome. 
Code works perfectly fine with Firefox and Safari. Fails 100% of the time with Chrome ... BUT, it works 100% of the time with Chrome if I have the console panel opened... Like bug is sentient and happens only when nobody is watching...

Comment: Hi - I might be reading it too literally, but if that *is* the complete code of your main.js then without a res.send() or res.render() call in 'done/:taskid' then it's not going to return anything to the browser and will hang/stall. 
If that isn't the complete code above, then is it possible there's some logic in the handler that's not causing the eventual res.render() or equivalent to fire for values 0 or 1 specifically, and that's what's causing it to hang/appear to not fire?
And if it IS hanging, it's also possible in some browsers/configurations its just timing out quicker than others...

Comment: Yeah, this is the complete code, but adding a `res.send()` doesn't change anything. When you hit a route that doesn't give you a response in chrome, you can see a spinner in your tab, where you usually would have a favicon, indicating that your browser is still waiting for an answer. 
But in my case when the bug occurs, I'm just redirected to '/', spinner is replaced by favicon indicating that the request has been processed (at least according to chrome), and that no further response is expected. Also, I don't have any log of my handler being called.

Comment: When the bug doesn't occur, (chrome console panel opened), The spinner stays in the tab, and I can see the log produced by my `console.log(req.params);` with the right value.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is something in the output from your twig.html is broken in a way that only confuses chrome. It's a stretch though. 
How about if you just go app.get('/done' ...) and pass the ID in as a query string? eg href='done?id=123'

Also I know this doesn't help with your specific problem, but just as an aside, GET requests generally shouldn't be use to change/update data on the server, for these kinds of reasons: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server

Comment: Holy shit it worked ! I changed my link into a <form method="post"> (and changed the routes accordingly), and it did the trick. Looks like your "aside" did fix my problem hahaha ! Thank you so much !
Still don't know what caused it, but i'm happy that it works.
May be some node restriction on what you can do with a GET (would be weird), or Chrome prefetching and deleting my data ahead of the click, as explained in your link (but that doesn't explain why I didn't get any log). Anyway, I can close this thread now, thanks man ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was fixed by changing my `<a href="">` into `<form method="post" ...>` and changing my routes accordingly. Still don't know what caused the problem, but it works now.

The links [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51534/andrew) provided in the comments hint toward chrome prefetching my links and modifying my data ahead of the click. Doesn't explain why I didn't get any log thought.

Morals of the story : don't use GET methods to modify/delete data.